# Wrap Panel in ListBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, wrappanel

I have the following XAML code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FriendsDataTemplate">
    <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ItemWidth="173" ItemHeight="233">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="183"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="FriendAvatar" Margin="1,1,11,11" Source="{Binding ImageURL}" Width="173" Height="173"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock x:Name="FriendName" Margin="0" Text="{Binding FriendName}" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,10,0" TextAlignment="Right"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </toolkit:WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<Grid x:Name="FriendsGrid">
    <ListBox x:Name="FriendsList" Margin="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FriendsDataTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

`FriendsList` width is 420px.

**My problem is**: I want two items column, but I see one.

Any advice?

Comment: You only have one element in your WrapPanel (the grid), so it is serving no purpose.  In your comment you mention Columns, but you are using Rows in your grid - not columns ...  Also, how are you populating your ListBox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the solution. Here is my working XAML code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FriendsDataTemplate">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="183"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="FriendAvatar" Margin="1,1,11,11" Source="{Binding ImageURL}" Width="173" Height="173"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock x:Name="FriendName" Margin="0" Text="{Binding FriendName}" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,10,0" TextAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<Grid x:Name="FriendsGrid">
    <ListBox x:Name="FriendsList" Margin="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FriendsDataTemplate}" Width="420">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemWidth="173" ItemHeight="233"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I've added a `ListBox.ItemsPanel` inside `ListBox` definition. And I've moved wrap panel on it.